# Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue: Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue

```
app.get('/status', (req, res) => { 
    res.send({ 
        messge: 'hello world!' 
    }) 
})
```

Somebody knows how to fix it ?

Comment: This is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/status', (req, res) => { 
res.json({ 
    messge: 'hello world!' 
}) })
```

It should be res.json for json data or you can send like this also

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({ messge: 'hello world!' }))
```